# Is there any guarantee that /usr/bin/env will exist?

Tags: scripting, env

Often I will see scripts begin with a shebang line that uses `#!/usr/bin/env interpreter_name` for whatever interpreter, with the rationale that different systems might have the interpreter that they need in order to run installed in different places. For instance, if I assume `python` is installed as `/usr/bin/python` then some user who decided to install it as `/opt/python` for some reason won't be able to use it as easily.

But the obvious question is, is there any guarantee that `env` will be installed at `/usr/bin/env` (or for that matter any particular place), or is this just a case of "moving the problem" so to speak?

[This slightly related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74484/usr-bin-env-zsh-no-such-file-or-directory) has a comment that says it's a bad idea and it's preferable to install it with the actual path of the interpreter and cites the single unix specification but does not really address this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `env` is not guaranteed to be in `/usr/bin`, as you can read in the [history of the shebang mechanism](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/), in the section "The env utility":

> However, the location of env(1) might vary. Free-, Net-, OpenBSD and some Linux distributions (e.g. Debian) only come with /usr/bin/env.
>   On the other hand, there's only /bin/env at least on SCO OpenServer 5.0.6 and Cray Unicos 9.0.2 (although the latter is only of historical interest).
>   On some other Linux distributions (Redhat) it's located in /bin and /usr/bin/ contains a symbolic link pointing to it.

It does not move the problem completely, because of the flexibility of `env` searching `$PATH`. If you happen to get some scripts that use a different location for `env` from yours, you **only** have to know about where your `env` lives, and not also where `perl`, `python`, and other interpreters might be installed.

And you don't have to hard code `/opt/python/3.3.2/bin/python3.3` if that is the first `python3.3` executable in your PATH. You can just rely on `env` finding it, so you don't have to update each and every script if you upgrade to use /opt/python/3.3.3/bin/python3.3. You script header stays the same:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.3
```

Comment: Aha. Thank you. I couldn't find any information on that.

When I said "moving" the problem I meant that instead of looking for `python` `perl` etc, you now just have to hunt down `env`, so the same problem, but a different target. It appears that `env` is a much easier to find though, and obviously much more versatile, so it's still vastly favorable. Which answers my question perfectly. Thank you!