# Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash not working on my system?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, shebang

I ran into some issues when running some installation scripts where they complained of `bad interpreter`.

So I made a trivial example but I can't figure out what the problem is, see below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "hello"
```

Executing the script above results in the following error

```
[root@ech-10-24-130-154 dc-user]# ./junk.sh
bash: ./junk.sh: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

The `/usr/bin/env` file exists, see below:

```
[root@ech-10-24-130-154 dc-user]# ls -l /usr/bin/env
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 27 04:14 /usr/bin/env -> ../../bin/env
[root@ech-10-24-130-154 dc-user]# ls -l /bin/env
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 23832 Jul 16  2014 /bin/env
[root@ech-10-24-130-154 dc-user]#
```

If I alter the script to use the regular shebang `#!/bin/bash` it works no problem. `#!/bin/env bash` works as well.

What is missing from the environment to allow the portable shebang to work?

`ls -lL /usr/bin/env` returns `ls: cannot access /usr/bin/env: No such file or directory` so I guess I need to alter the symbolic link? Can I point it to `/bin/env`?

`env --version` is 8.4 and the OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6.

Comment: Usually that's due to carriage-return/line-feed endings on the lines. Alternatively: [location of env](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111802/is-there-any-guarantee-that-usr-bin-env-will-exist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ls -lL /usr/bin/env` shows that the symbolic link is broken. That explains why the shebang line isn't working: the kernel is trying, and obviously failing, to execute a dangling symbolic link.

`/usr/bin/env -> ../../bin/env` is correct if `/usr` and `/usr/bin` are both actual directories (not symlinks). Evidently this isn't the case on your machine. Maybe `/usr` is a symbolic link? (Evidently it isn't a symbolic link to `/`, otherwise `/usr/bin/env` would be the same file as `/bin/env`, not a symbolic link).

You need to fix that symbolic link. You can make it an absolute link:

```
sudo ln -snf /bin/env /usr/bin/env
```

You can make it a relative link, but if you do, make sure it's correct. Switch to `/usr/bin` and run `ls -l relative/path/to/bin/env` to confirm that you've got it right before creating the symlink.

This isn't a default RHEL setup, so you must have modified something locally. Try to find out what you did and whether that could have caused other similar problems.

Comment: This is correct, `/usr/bin` was moved to another file system and is a symbolic link to `/vol_01/usr/bin`

Comment: @conorgriffin: What OS was that, please?

Comment: It's in the question :) "env --version is 8.4 and the OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6."

Answer (score 0):

So... I was getting a similar error but for /usr/bin/sh not being found and was also telling me the script I was trying to run was not found as I am running it! I verified location of sh in /usr/bin so was baffled and came here looking for answers...

In my case, I was editing in UltraEdit and forgot to convert the DOS CR LF's to Unix LFs.  DOH!

Once I did that and re-imported script it found sh just fine.  I had other issues to work out but this mystery issue was solved.

Answer (score -1):

Here (Fedora 23) `/bin` is a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`; if you have a similar setup, the symbolic link from `/usr/bin/env` just buys you an infinite loop.

Check the relevant packages, i.e. `rpm -qf /usr/bin/env /bin/env`, and reinstall those (here `coreutils`, i.e.. `yum reinstall coreutils` or similar). That should fix any misguided manhandling.

Comment: I already reinstalled `coreutils` but that made no difference.  It's pretty weird. `/usr/bin/env` is a symbolic link with a relative path to it's target `../../bin/env`.  So that should be `/bin/env` which also exists.  So I don't understand why that symbolic link doesn't work.  I replaced the target so it points to `/bin/env` with an absolute path and that seems to have worked.

Comment: If `/bin` was a symbolic link to `/usr/bin` on conorgriffin's system, then `/usr/bin/env` and `/bin/env` would be the same file.