# output of which perl is /bin/perl instead of /usr/bin/perl

Tags: rhel, path, which

Hi I'm running Redhat Server 7.9 and running into an interesting issue. If I type `which perl`, I get `/bin/perl`, but it should be `/usr/bin/perl`. The same for `git`.

This same machine would print `/usr/` before, but it doesn't know.

Im a little confused, why would this change?

Comment: On a CentOS 7.9 server, /bin is a symbolic link to /usr/bin. Should be the same on a REL system. the output of `which perl` depends on the order set in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any guarantee that /usr/bin/env will exist?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111802/is-there-any-guarantee-that-usr-bin-env-will-exist)

Comment: It was the order of $PATH. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to use `command -v` rather than `which`. `command -v perl`

Comment: If @doneal24 doesn't post an actual answer, please [feel free to do it yorurself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) so this doesn't keep popping up as Unanswered in the future.

Answer (score 0):

On a CentOS 7.9 server, /bin is a symbolic link to /usr/bin. Should be the same on a REL system. the output of `which perl` depends on the order set in your `$PATH`.