# How to control buffering of pipes in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, buffer, shebang

I need my script to be executed with `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0` otherwise user will wonder why there is no output (becuase of pipe buffer). How can I acheive it?

```
#!/usr/bin/stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 /bin/bash
```

results in

```
/usr/bin/stdbuf: invalid mode ‘0 -o0 -e0 /bin/bash’
```

Comment: Hauke Laging's answer gives a workaround. See [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74484/usr-bin-env-zsh-no-such-file-or-directory/74488#74488) for why your attempt failed: the shebang mechanism under Linux only allows a single argument.

Answer (score 10):

Usually there is no need to unbuffer the whole script. This is necessary with certain programs only.

But if you want to do it that way you can simply call the script from itself:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ yes != "$STDBUF" ]; then
    STDBUF=yes /usr/bin/stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 "$0"
    exit $?
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Appears there are two suboptimal solutions:

- https://serverfault.com/a/589614/70242
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25375/14907

Suboptimal at least when you provide input to command. Otherwise they might be both ok. `script` records your input and `unbuffer` just doesn't let you input properly. YMMV